# When is an inverse a multifunction?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

Define $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^2$. If $f^{-1}(x)$ is interpreted as a function, it is undefined, since $f$ is not injective. If $f^{-1}$ is interpreted as a multifunction, it returns $\{-\sqrt{x},\sqrt{x}\}$. When is each of these interpretations normally made?

Comment: It depends on the level of math at which you are studying.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\{-x, x\} $.

Comment: @AndrewChin BSc, questions like "Find $f^{-1}(x)$".

Comment: @MattSamuel Wouldn't that be $f^{-1}(\{x^2\})$?

Comment: Oh, you're right. Nevermind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why we include domains and codomains in function definitions.  Given an invertible mapping $f:A\to B$, the inverse mapping is $f^{-1}:B\to A$.  Given any mapping $f:A\to B$, the preimage mapping is $f^{-1}:\mathcal P(B)\to\mathcal P(A)$, where $\mathcal P(X)$ refers to the power set of $X$.

Therefore, $f^{-1}(2)$ would refer to the inverse function, and $f^{-1}(\{2\})$ would refer to the pre-image function.

In practice, few people work with domains where there is any risk of not understanding which function is meant.  I will note that my foundations professor who had noble but futile dreams of fixing mathematical notation, thought that $f_>$ and $f^<$ were distinct but still clear notations indicating the image and pre-image functions.

Comment: I think this might be the answer I've been looking for. Can you clarify what $P$ refers to?

Comment: @mjc $\mathcal P(X)$ is the power-set of $X$, i.e. the set of all subsets of $X$.

Comment: Is the idea here that defining the domain and co-domain of the pre-image function $f^{-1}:P(B) \to P(A)$ means $f$ need not be injective for $f^{-1}$ to be defined, since $f^{-1}(x)$ targets a single element, namely a non-empty set?

Comment: @mjc Right.  The pre-image function is defined as $f^{-1}(S)=\{x\in A\mid f(x)\in S\}$ (not just for singletons but for any subset of the codomain).  Because the codomain of the pre-image function is a subset of $A$, the underlying function does not need to be either injective or surjective for the function to be well-defined.

Comment: Thanks for this. If you still have the patience, I have a couple more questions. Q1. Can we say that the pre-image function is a representative of a class of inverse functions, with the property that every function has a pre-image function? Q2. Given sets $A=\{a,b,c\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$ and $f:A \to B$ given by $f(a)=1, f(b)=2$, would the following statements be correct? i) $S_B=\{1,2\} \subseteq B$ is the image both of $A$ and of $S_A=\{a,b\} \subseteq A$; ii) $S_A$ is the pre-image both of $B$ and of $S_B$.

Comment: I really wish $f_>$ and $f^{<}$ were more popular. It makes talking about things like $f_{>>}$ or $(f_{>})^<$ easier. The only text reference for that notation I know is [Basic Language of Mathematics](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/9117), but if you know of another I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: @MarkS. Alas, my foundations professor was Walter Noll, Dr. Schäffer's colleague at Carnegie Mellon and my class notes were the larval form of that textbook back in the late '80's!  The one text I have that uses it is Noll's "Finite Dimensional Spaces", which can be downloaded from http://www.math.cmu.edu/~wn0g/noll/.

Answer (score 1):

We define inverse of an element as other element of the same kind such that their product is identity.In other words notion of inverse is understood as defined in case of groups. So this means inverse of a single valued function is expected to be a single valued function only unless otherwise stated. If obviously one is not restricting to single valued function then multiple valued functions are also acceptable as inverses and suitably the inverse is defined in that case.